# Why is "javascript:" prepended to onchange in this html code?

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I have seen the following HTML when viewing source code in Chrome:

```
<select class="menu_combo" onchange="javascript:myfunction()">
<!-- rest of code goes here -->
```

Why is the word `javascript` and a colon (`:`) added in front of `myfunction()`? I thought that `onchange` was a javascript event. If so, what is the need for this?

Comment: As you say, it's not really needed.

Comment: There is no need for this. Some people generalize the `javascript:` prefix used in `href` attributes (which is itself a misuse of an obscure browser feature).

Comment: *"Why is “javascript:” prepended to onchange in this html code?"* Because the person writing it didn't know what they were doing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for it; it’s a mistake/misconception by the author. It still works because it’s a valid label, used properly with loops:

```
loop: while (true) {
    while (true) {
        break loop;
    }
}
```